# can you have a lookup search contacts and accounts?

Tags: lookup, account

I have a custom object that contains a lookup field and I want to search on contact and accounts.

Answer (score 4):

Custom polymorphic lookups are not supported by the platform at this time. Go vote for [the idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqzBAAS) now.

Unless, of course, you have Person Accounts enabled, which lets you lookup contacts and person accounts (but not business accounts).